# AngularJS: How to escape JSON key that has operator in it?

Tags: angularjs, json, escaping

This is an AngularJS syntax question.

{ "key-part": "value-part" } is a valid JSON object. However, in AngularJS, {{ x.key-part }} is an expression. It does not return "value-part" but returns 0. Any idea how to escape the '-'?

Yes, you may ask why use "key-part" instead of "key_part". Well, I have no control over that.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can access attributes of an object like a standard Javascript object : https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_properties.asp

So `<span>{{myObject['attr']}}</span>` work

```js
"use strict";

angular.module("demo", [])
  .controller("MainController", MainController);

function MainController() {
  var vm = this;
  vm['da-ta'] = "data";
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demo" ng-controller="MainController as main">
  <div ng-bind="main['da-ta']"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `{{ x["key-part"] }}` instead of `{{ x.key-part }}`.

**Working Demo**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.x = { "key-part": "value-part" };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  {{ x["key-part"] }} 
</div>
```